# Populating a Treeview from an Access database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, ms-access, treeview

I am trying to populate a Treeview from an Access Database table.

The idea is to have the province as the Parent node, then the city as the child node, then the suburb as the child to that child node.

I have this some code already but `arrParentType = nParent.Tag.Split("=");` wont work and i dont know why.

is there someone that can help me with this problem?

```
 void tvProvincesFill()
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = E:\Users\Me\Documents\C# Projects\MyProject1\Data\database.accdb; Persist Security Info =False;");

    OleDbDataReader treeProvince;
    OleDbCommand cmdSelectProvinces = new OleDbCommand(("SELECT Province.Province_Code, Province.Province_name " + ("FROM (Province) " + ("GROUP BY Province.Province_Code, Province.Province_name " + ("HAVING Province.Province_name<>\' \' " + "ORDER BY Province.Province_name")))), con);
    if ((con.State != ConnectionState.Open))
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    treeProvince = cmdSelectProvinces.ExecuteReader();
    while (treeProvince.Read())
    {
        TreeNode nProvince = new TreeNode();
        nProvince.Text = treeProvince["Province_name"].ToString();
        nProvince.Tag = ("Province_Code=" + treeProvince["Province_Code"].ToString());
        this.treeView1.Nodes.Add(nProvince);
        tvProvincesLoadChildNodes(nProvince);
        // Load City and suburb info for current province
        nProvince = null;
    }

    //   frmMain.lblProvince.BackColor = Color.Empty
    treeProvince = null;
    cmdSelectProvinces = null;
}

// Fill Provinces for Geographic Criteria
void tvProvincesLoadChildNodes(TreeNode nParent)
{
    // Load City and Suburb sub nodes for Provinces
    string[] arrParentType;
    arrParentType = nParent.Tag.Split("=");
    if ((arrParentType[0] == "Province_Code"))
    {
        // Add City sub-nodes
        OleDbDataReader drCities;
        OleDbCommand cmdGetCities = new OleDbCommand(("SELECT Area_File.City " + ("FROM (Area_File) " + ("GROUP BY Area_File.City, Area_File.Province_Code " + ("HAVING Area_File.City<>\' \' AND Area_File.Province_Code="
                        + (arrParentType[1] + " ORDER BY Area_File.City"))))), con);
        drCities = cmdGetCities.ExecuteReader();
        while (drCities.Read())
        {
            TreeNode nCity = new TreeNode();
            nCity.Text = drCities["City"].ToString();
            nCity.Tag = ("City=" + drCities["City"].ToString());
            nParent.Nodes.Add(nCity);
            tvProvincesLoadChildNodes(nCity);
            //  Load Suburbs for current city node
            nCity = null;
        }

        drCities = null;
        cmdGetCities = null;
    }
    else if ((arrParentType[0] == "City"))
    {
        // Add Suburb sub-nodes
        OleDbDataReader drSuburbs;
        OleDbCommand cmdGetSuburbs = new OleDbCommand(("SELECT Area_File.Suburb " + ("FROM (Area_File) " + ("GROUP BY Area_File.Suburb, Area_File.City " + ("HAVING Area_File.Suburb<>\' \' AND Area_File.City=\'"
                        + (arrParentType[1] + ("\'" + " ORDER BY Area_File.Suburb")))))), con);
        drSuburbs = cmdGetSuburbs.ExecuteReader();
        while (drSuburbs.Read())
        {
            TreeNode nSuburb = new TreeNode();
            nSuburb.Text = drSuburbs["Suburb"].ToString();
            nSuburb.Tag = ("Suburb=" + drSuburbs["Suburb"].ToString());
            nParent.Nodes.Add(nSuburb);
            nSuburb = null;
        }

        drSuburbs.Close();
        cmdGetSuburbs = null;
    }

    arrParentType = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two things that would prevent the code from working:

1. TreeNode.Tag is an object and cannot be split. You need to cast it to a string first using ToString().
2. The split function requires a character as it's parameter. You are supplying it with a string. Use .Split('=') instead of .Split("=").

If you change the line where you split the tag to:

```
arrParentType = nParent.Tag.ToString().Split('=');
```

It should work fine.

Hope this helps.